# Storing settings: XML vs. SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sqlite, ado.net

I am currently writing an IRC client and I've been trying to figure out a good way to store the server settings. Basically a big list of networks and their servers as most IRC clients have.

I had decided on using SQLite but then I wanted to make the list freely available online in XML format (and perhaps definitive), for other IRC apps to use. So now I may just store the settings locally in the same format.

I have very little experience with either ADO.NET or XML so I'm not sure how they would compare in a situation like this.

Is one easier to work with programmatically? Is one faster? Does it matter?

Comment: How big is this list? How many records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a vaguer question than you realize.  "Settings" can encompass an awful lot of things.

There's a good .NET infrastructure for handling application settings in configuration files.  These, generally, are exposed to your program as properties of a global Settings object; the classes in the `System.Configuration` namespace take care of reading and persisting them, and there are tools built into Visual Studio to auto-generate the code for dealing with them.  One of the data types that this infrastructure supports is `StringCollection`, so you could use that to store a list of servers.

But for a large list of servers, this wouldn't be my first choice, for a couple of reasons.  I'd expect that the elements in your list are actually tuples (e.g. host name, port, description), not simple strings, in which case you'll end up having to format and parse the data to get it into a `StringCollection`, and that is generally a sign that you should be doing something else.  Also, application settings are read-only (under Vista, at least), and while you can give a setting user scope to make it persistable, that leads you down a path that you probably want to understand before committing to.

So, another thing I'd consider:  Is your list of servers simply a list, or do you have an internal object model representing it?  In the latter case, I might consider using XML serialization to store and retrieve the objects.  (The only thing I'd keep in the application configuration file would be the path to the serialized object file.)  I'd do this because serializing and deserializing simple objects into XML is really easy; you don't have to be concerned with designing and testing a proper serialization format because the tools do it for you.

The primary reason I look at using a database is if my program performs a bunch of operations whose results need to be atomic and durable, or if for some reason I don't want all of my data in memory at once.  If every time X happens, I want a permanent record of it, that's leading me in the direction of using a database.  You don't want to use XML serialization for something like that, generally, because you can't realistically serialize just one object if you're saving all of your objects to a single physical file.  (Though it's certainly not crazy to simply serialize your whole object model to save one change.  In fact, that's exactly what my company's product does, and it points to another circumstance in which I wouldn't use a database:  if the data's schema is changing frequently.)

Comment: I'm not sure what "atomic and durable" means, could you explain?

Comment: They're both attributes of transactions.  A transaction is indivisible, like an atom:  either all the operations in a transaction happen or they all don't.  "Durable" means that once the transaction is committed, it's saved in some form that will endure, say, the power going out.  (They're also consistent and isolated:  see the Wikipedia entry for ACID.)

Comment: XML file corruption is an awful thing on app startup. Try it! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use XML for settings - .NET is already built to do this and as such has many built-in facilities for storing your settings in XML configuration files.

If you want to use a custom schema (be it XML or DB) for storing settings then I would say that either XML or SQLite will work just as well since you ought to be using a decent API around the data store.

Comment: There is a .NET wrapper for SQLite

Answer (score 2):

**Every tool has its own right**

There is plenty of hype arround XML, I know. But you should see, that XML is basically an exchange format -- not a storage format (unless you use a native XML-Database that gives you more options -- but also might add some headaches).

When your configuration is rather small (say less than 10.000 records), you might use XML and be fine. You will load the whole thing into your memory and access the entries there. Done.

But when your configuration is so big, that you dont want to load it completely, than you rethink your decission and stay with SQLite which gives you the option to dynamically load those parts of the configuration you need.

You could also provide a little tool to create a XML file from the DB-content -- creation of XML from a DB is a rather simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have two separate applications here: a web server and a desktop client (because that is traditionally where these things run), each with its own storage needs.

On the server side: go with a relational data store, not Xml.  Basically at some point you need to keep user data separate from other user data on the server.  XML is not a good store for that.

On the client: it doesn't really matter.  Xml will probably be easier for you to manipulate. And don't think that because you are using one technology in one setting, you have to use it in the other.

Comment: I was referring to serving the XML file on the web for others to use.

Comment: Persistence is an issue with the web and files.  It is often easier to store the data in a database, then -- if you need to -- transform the results to xml.  Databases make persistence easy (ok, easier).